# Abelian subcategory

Tags: homological-algebra

Can somebody give me an example of a subcategory of an abelian category which is also an abelian category, but not an abelian *subcategory* (which means some kernels or cokernels are different from the initial ones).

Comment: The category of presheaves of abelian groups on a space $X$ is abelian, as  is the subcategory of sheaves. But the inclusion
is not generally right exact, so the cokernels can differ.

Comment: @Donu, why don't you make that an answer? :)

Comment: Thank you, Donu. Is there a simpler example?

Comment: Take any nontrivial abelian category A and any object a not isomorphic to the zero object.  Then the subcategory consisting of the object a together with its identity map is abelian, but not an abelian subcategory.  

Comment: Also, the question states that the only way in which a subcategory can fail to be a sub-Abelian-category is if it has different (co)kernels.  But this isn't so: another way it can fail is if it has different (co)products or a different zero object (as in my example). 

Comment: Tom, do I understand it right - in your example you put a different abelian group structure on the set of morphisms in the subcategory? Identity morphism of a plays a role of the zero, doesn't it? That's probably not what we expect when we say a subcategory.

Comment: @Tom. It should have the same zero object - one can consider the kernel of any identity map. Similarly with the direct sums - one can consider an exact sequence  $O\to A \to A\oplus B \to B \to 0$ sequence in the subcategory, that should stay exact in the initial subcategory. Thus your example can not work.  

Comment: This is related, and similarly puzzling, so let me add it: I happen to have listened today to a very nice talk by Amnon Yekutieli on his paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4386 with Marco Porta, Liran Shaul, where among many other things, they construct a rather natural full subcategory $D(\mathrm{Mod} A)_{\mathfrak a-\mathrm{com}}$ of $D(\mathrm{Mod} A)$ of the «cohomologically $\mathfrak{a}$-adically complete complexes» (for a commutative ring $A$ with an ideal $\mathfrak a$) which has arbitrary direct sums, but these direct sums are not the same as those in $D(\mathrm{Mod} A)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small example of a full subcategory that is abelian, but not an abelian subcategory:

Let $k$ be a field and let $R_n$ denote the ring of upper triangular $n \times n$-matrices over $k$. Then $mod (R_3)$ is an abelian category with $6$ indecomposable objects (up to isomorphism). There is a unique indecomposable object $P$ of length $3$. It has a simple socle $s(P)$ and a simple top $t(P)$. Consider the full additive subcategory with indecomposable objects $P$, $s(P)$, and $t(P)$. This category is equivalent to $mod (R_2)$ and therefore abelian. It is not an abelian subcategory since the lengths do not add up in $mod (R_3)$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am not supposed to ask how you are doing in the comments, so I won't do that :)

Comment: @Dag. Do you consider the category of finitely generated R_n modules? Could you give a more explicit description of the indecomposable representations of R_n? It must be classical, do you know a good reference? 

Comment: @Victor. Yes, it is the category of finitely generated $R_n$-modules, but I don't think it matters in this example. Honestly, I was considering the equivalent category of repreresentations of the quiver $A_n$ with "linear orientation". Here is an online reference: arXiv:math/0505082v1. Hope this helps.